# How to access a click handler in custom attribute in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

Is it possible to access click handler of the element in the custom attribute? I would like to achieve something like this:

```html
<button click.delegate="callSomeMethod()" log-click>Click</button>
```

where `log-click` is a custom attribute that wraps the `click` call and decorates it with some behavior.

A non-working example, but showing what I want to achieve:

```js
class LogClickCustomAttribute {
  @bindable click;
  attached() {
    let originalClick = this.click;
    this.click = () => {
      console.log('decoreated!');
      return originalClick();
    };
  }
}
```

The real use case I am trying to achieve is a button that disables itself until promise returned by `click` handler resolves. [Like promise-btn for Angular](https://github.com/johannesjo/angular-promise-buttons).

```html
<button click.delegate="request()" disable-until-request-resolves>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea if it is possible to access attributes of standard HTML elements like `button` within a custom attribute. However this is easy if you create a custom element for buttons:

GistRun: https://gist.run/?id=d18de213112c5f21631da457f218ca3f

**custom-button.html**

```
<template>
  <button click.delegate="onButtonClicked()">Test</button>
</template>
```

**custom-button.js**

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class CustomButton {
  @bindable() onClicked;

  onButtonClicked() {
    if (typeof this.onClicked === 'function') {
      this.onClicked();
    }
  }
}
```

**log-click.js**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {CustomButton} from 'custom-button';

@inject(CustomButton)
export class LogClickCustomAttribute {
  constructor(customButton) {
    this.customButton = customButton;
  }

  bind() {
    let originalOnClicked = this.customButton.onClicked;

    this.customButton.onClicked = () => {
      console.log('decorated!');
      return originalOnClicked();
    };
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="./custom-button"></require>
  <require from="./log-click"></require>
  <custom-button on-clicked.call="test()" log-click>Test</custom-button>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```
export class App {
  test() {
    console.log("The button was clicked.");
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. They want to create an custom attribute, not a custom element.

Comment: It does answer OP's question. My `log-click` is a custom attribute that can be used with my `custom-button` custom element.

Comment: Yes. Sorry I misspoke, but still, OP wants to handle this on standard elements.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I put the custom attribute requirement because I was biased by the solution from Angular. The custom components works great. As I am always finding it *really* hard to publish anything as a package in *modern JS*, all I can to is to publish [aurelia promise button gist](https://gist.github.com/fracz/1536a2db1a2eb10ae7b8e41692a0a3ed).

Answer (score 3):

You can add event handlers to the element in the constructor of the custom attribute.

```
    @inject(Element)
    export class ClickThisCustomAttribute {

        constructor(element) {
            element.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.doSomething();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the listener when the view model is detached!

Answer (score 1):

Given how Aurelia attaches event handlers, you're not going to be able to do exactly what you want.

That being said, you could use a simple custom attribute like the one below to log out an event to the console:

**log-event.js**

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element)
export class LogEventCustomAttribute {
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el;
  }

  attached() {
    const eventName = this.value || 'click';

    let handler = (e) => console.log('event logged', e);

    if (this.el.addEventListener) { // DOM standard
      this.el.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false)
    } else if (this.el.attachEvent) { // IE
      this.el.attachEvent(eventName, handler)
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: OP says, "The real use case I am trying to achieve is a button that disables itself until promise returned by click handler resolves. Like promise-btn for Angular." I don't see where you have access to the click handler function within the custom attribute, which is necessary to be able to get a returned promise from it so the button can be enabled after the promise resolves.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the listener when the view model is detached!

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to a promise click I made was this:

```
import { autoinject, bindable } from "aurelia-framework";

@autoinject
export class PromiseClickCustomAttribute {
  @bindable({ primaryProperty: true }) delegate: Function;

  constructor(private element: Element) {
    this.element.addEventListener("click", async () => {
        try {
          this.element.classList.add("disabled");
          this.element.classList.add("loading");
          await this.delegate();
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
        finally {
            this.element.classList.remove("disabled");
            this.element.classList.remove("loading");
        }
    })
  }
}
```

```
<div class="ui container">
    <h2>Promise Click</h2>
    <div class="ui input">
        <button class="ui button" promise-click.call="alertLater()">Toast Later</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
alertLater = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        alert("Promise Resolved");
        resolve();
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Great solution, but note this works better with `.call` binding command as it preserves `this` context.
`promise-click.call="alertLater"`
https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/basics#function-references

Comment: Good point, I actually updated this at a later date. When using `call` you call the method with the parentheses which is nice as it brings it in line with the way you call other Aurelia methods on a normal click. `promise-click.call="alertLater()"` I also wrapped the click in a try catch